# WebStorm: turn off auto deletion for unused imprts

Tags: webstorm, auto-import

I like the optimized imports a lot except for one behavior that I want to get rid of.

So if I make a bracket mistake in my JSX and use an imported library below this mistake it automatically removes this import on save. Then I fix the issue and now my imports are gone and I have to get them manually back (or copy my changes and `command + z` until they are back again and paste my new changes).

This is really annoying so **I'm searching for the option to turn off deletion for unused imports in WebStorm**.

Comment: No, "Optimize imports" can't be customized, and removing unused imports is one of its core features...

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that suppressing **JavaScript and TypeScript | Imports and dependencies | Unused ES6 / TypeScript imports** inspection for particular import or for the whole file with `// noinspection ES6UnusedImports` helps:

```
// noinspection ES6UnusedImports
import {Bar} from "bar";
```